# How do the authorities know whether someone reaches a country?

Tags: air-travel

In Poland there are 10 days of quarantine for people arriving in Poland. Consider that someone arrives in Poland from Istanbul through Amsterdam. How do the officers know that he arrived in Poland, since the passport control was in the Netherlands and nobody checked the person when they entered Poland? Does KLM give the person's name to the police? Is this possible?

---

can somebody explain this to me. Since 23 January ... what does this mean? If I have a test 48 hours before entering poland then no quarantine is required? Right?[image]

https://www.gov.pl/web/coronavirus/travel

Comment: What assurance is there that "nobody checked the person in Poland?" Passport control may not take place in Poland if you've already passed through another Schengen country, but they can setup checkpoints for COVID restrictions, and it appears [Warsaw Airport has done just that](https://www.lotnisko-chopina.pl/en/covid-19-testing-point.html) (see the bit that mentions "before COVID test certificates’ checkpoint." The officers there can determine whether you're coming from a Schengen or non-Schengen country by checking your travel documents or even possibly taking your word for it.

Comment: Why do you ask? If you are planning to go to Poland, please do yourself and all others around you a favor and follow the quarantine rules, regardless of and how you are being tracked.

Comment: Note that if you have a Turkish passport, it is likely it will be up to you to prove that you were not in Turkey for whatever duration is necessary to avoid quarantine, rather than up to them to prove the opposite. But passport stamps, boarding passes, luggage tags, PNR lookups and more are very easy ways for them to prove it anyway. Don’t even think about trying to fool them, it could end badly for you.

Comment: Nobody checked I came yesterday.

Comment: Turkan, repeated, do not post in the answers fields unless it is a real answer. Best do not post in those fields at all as you do not seem to understand the difference.

Comment: Ok sorry. So I ask my question here or in new topic?

Comment: If you have a new question, then ask your new question using the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

The formal entering of the Schengen area will be in your first airport within the area, as usual.
But special rules will allow Poland to check and record your details.

The airline may well give details, they usually do for some countries, although not within Schengen as far as I know.

If countries feel there is a need, COVID 19 rules do allow other measures like quarantaine in apointed locations.

Comment: I am not thinking about fooling why some people instead of answering just accusing me. All checks were in Amsterdam. My question is while entering poland nobody highlighted me to do anything just ask about the test and check it. How they check that person this is my question

Comment: I am trying to help you, warn you how they may keep an eye on you. As countries do not always let people know if and how they keep track of people we can often only guess what they do. We try to help you not to run into problems by warning where they might come up.